# sharepoint header trying to get the background to change based on a status

Tags: sharepoint, colors, header

I am trying to get the header of a sharepoint submission form to change color based on what a status says.

I sas able to get the header to contain the status ex: In progress and the reservation # as pictured, but I cannot get the background of the header color to change based on the status

I cannot get the code to work any help would be greatly appreciated code part 4 is what I am trying to get the color to change

Thanks

I cannot get the color to change I provided pictures of the code

[submission form header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJHGi.png)

1. "elmType": "div",    "attributes": {
   "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"    },    "style": {
   "width": "99%",
   "border-top-width": "0px",
   "border-bottom-width": "1px",
   "border-left-width": "0px",
   "border-right-width": "0px",
   "border-style": "solid",
   "margin-bottom": "16px"    },    "children": [
   {
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
   "display": "flex",
   "box-sizing": "border-box",
   "align-items": "center"
   },
   "children": [
   {
   "elmType": "div",
   "attributes": {
   "iconName": "Vacation",
   "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
   "title": "Details"
   },
   "style": {
   "flex": "none",
   "padding": "0px",
   "padding-left": "0px",
   "height": "36px"
   }
   }
   ]
   },
   {
   "elmType": "div",
   "attributes": {
   "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
   },
   "style": {
   "box-sizing": "border-box",
   "width": "100%",
   "text-align": "left",
   "padding": "21px 12px",
   "overflow": "hidden"
   },
   "children": [
   {
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=[ $Status] + ' Reservation Number ' + [$Reservation_x0020_Number ]"
   }
   ]
   }    ] } {   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div", "txtContent": "@currentField", "style": {
   "background-color": "=if([$Status] =='Not Started' , 'grey',
   if([$Status] == 'Completed-Fixed by Other' ,'#0078d4', 'green',
   if([$Status] == 'In Progress' ,'#106ebe', 'themeDarkAlt',
   if([$Status] == 'Completed-Fixed by Other' ,'#0078d4', 'green'))))”
   "padding-left": "14px"

Comment: Can you copy-paste the code and add to your question instead of images of code? Also, are you trying to change the color of list form header or column header in list view? It is unclear in your question. Where exactly you want to apply the color, can you add screenshot from SharePoint and highlight where exactly you want to apply the colors?

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide the code (in text form)?
I can try to modify your code for you.
I did a test to simulate your scene, and I found that the color you used could not be recognized. I used the officially supported color, which can change the background color according to the value of the state.
Here is  code for your reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Status] =='Not Started' , 'grey', if([$Status] == 'In Progress' ,'#0078d4', 'green'))",
    "padding-left": "14px"
  }
}
```

[image: Here is test result]

[image: Here is theme color]

Here is link about color for your reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/themes-colors